# Using 'If' and 'ElseIf' with get-childitem from different directories

Tags: powershell, if-statement, get-childitem

There are 3 directories that I want to take the files from out of 20 directories. And I have a GUI set up to output a `$year` variable. The options being 2017, 2018, 2019 and Select All.
With the files I want to copy them to a different folder, preferably with folder structure intact.

```
$year = '2018'

if ($year = '2017') {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2017' -Recurse
} elseif ($year = '2018') {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2018' -Recurse
} elseif ($year = '2019') {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2019' -Recurse
} elseif ($year = 'Select All') {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2017'
    Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2018'
    Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2019'
} else {
    "This didn'nt work"
}
# = files
```

This was the idea, It doesn't work. I want the output of this to be put into the variable $files because of the code below. I am more than open to alternative ways of doing this but this seemed the most logical from a newbie perspective.

```
foreach ($file in $files){
    $sourcePathFile = $file.FullName
    $destinationPathFile = $file.FullName.Replace($sourcePath,  $destinationPath)

    $exists = Test-Path $destinationPathFile

    if (!$exists) {
        $dir = Split-Path -Parent $destinationPathFile
        if (!(Test-Path($dir))) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $dir }
        Copy-Item -Path $sourcePathFile -Destination $destinationPathFile -Recurse -Force
    } else{
        $isFile = Test-Path -Path $destinationPathFile -PathType Leaf

        if ($isFile) {
            $different = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $sourcePathFile) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $destinationPathFile)
            if (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $sourcePathFile) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $destinationPathFile)) {
                $dir = Split-Path -Parent $destinationPathFile
                if (!(Test-Path($dir))) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $dir }
                Copy-Item -Path $sourcePathFile -Destination $destinationPathFile -Recurse -Force
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In conditional statements (like `if`), equality is represented by the operator `-eq` and not `=`. `=` does assignment.

Comment: Thanks @AdminOfThings that worked, do you know how do I save it as a variable though?. i.e. second part of my post

Comment: Yep. You can set the entire if-else code block to a variable. `$files = if () {}; else {}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In conditional statements that make a comparison, you should consider using the [Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6). Equals is represented by the operator `-eq`. `=` is used for variable assignment. You can transform your code to reflect this. The output of the `if-else` block can be set to a variable (`$files`).

```
$files = 
    If ($year -eq '2017') {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2017'  -Recurse
     } 
    ElseIf ($year -eq '2018') {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2018'  -Recurse
    }   
    ElseIf ($year -eq '2019') {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2019'  -Recurse
    }     
    ElseIf ($year -eq 'Select All') {
       Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2017' 
       Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2018' 
       Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2019'  
        }
    Else {    
        "This didn't work"
    }
```

---

If your particular situation, you may have unexpected results outside of just the operator issue. Consider the following example:

```
If ($year = '2017') {
   "It is 2017"
} Else {
    "Wrong year"
}

It is 2017
$year
2017
```

If `$year` can be successfully assigned a value that would normally evaluate to `$true` in a condition, then the `if` condition will be true ***and*** `$year` will be updated with the new value.

Consider the following example of when the `if` will not evaluate to `$true`. Here `0` evaluates to `$false` ***and*** the assignment was successful in updating `$year` to `0`.

```
If ($year = 0) {
   "It is 2017"
} Else {
    "Wrong year"
}

Wrong year
$year
0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an opportunity for a switch as well:

```
$year = 2017,2018

$files = switch ($year) {  # $year can be an array
  2017 { dir $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2017' -R } 
  2018 { dir $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2018' -R } 
  2019 { dir $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2019' -R } 
  'Select All' {
    dir $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2017',
      $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2018',
      $sourcePath'\Warranty Claims 2019'
  } 
  default {"This didn't work"}
}

$files
```